# I am trying to make a discord.py verification system using the on_raw_reaction_add event

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command(name='verify')
            async def verify(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
                msg = await channel.send('React to this message')
                await msg.add_reaction('')
            
                @client.event
                async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
                    print('payload message.id ' + str(payload.message_id))
                    print('messages.id ' + str(msg.id)
```

Can someone explain how will this will work

Comment: That's not gonna work, ever

Comment: Why?
I am new to discord.py

Comment: Because you don't put events inside commands, if you want to wait for an event (like a reply or a reaction) you should use `wait_for`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing that in a simple way

**First way** (not recommended if you want it to work forever once you run the command. But if you want it like that, then choose this)

```py
@bot.command() # since you are using client, replace bot with client
async def verify(ctx): # I left out "channel" because I don't know what you want to do with it
    # Same thing as you did
    msg = await ctx.send("React to this message")
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    # Waiting for someone to react
    def check(payload):
        return payload.message_id == msg.id # This will check if the message reacted on is the same as the bot's message, if you want it to be the user as well, replace this line with "return payload.message_id == msg.id and payload.user_id == ctx.author.id"
    payload = await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check) # You can add a timeout like this: "payload = await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check, timeout=int)"
    if str(payload.emoji) == "":
        print(f"{payload.member} reacted")
```

**Second way** (harder but useful if you want to run the command once, but if your bot turns off, it'll reset, so have some sort of save file to save `verify_msg`)

```py
# This list is going to have all the verification messages
verify_msg = []

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global verify_msg
    # check if the message id match to one of the messages' in the list
    for msg in verify_msg:
        if payload.message_id in msg.id: # success
            if str(payload.emoji) == "":
                print(f"{payload.member} reacted")
                return # exit from the command (you can replace it with "break" if you want to continue)

@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    global verify_msg
    msg = await ctx.send("React to this message")
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    # add the message to the list
    verify_msg.append(msg)
```

### References:

- [await bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [payload](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#rawreactionactionevent)
- [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

Comment: so in the first method i have to put  a while true loop over here
`if str(payload.emoji) == "":
                print(f"{payload.member} reacted")
                return # exit from the command (you can replace it with "break" if you want to continue)`

Comment: if you want it running forever (but it is resource consuming unless you use timeout), yes you can

Answer (score 0):

You do not put events inside commands, you can use `client.wait_for`

```py
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    msg = await channel.send("React to this message")
    await msg.add_reaction('')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and reaction.message == msg
    # Waiting for the reaction
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    print(f"{ctx.author} reacted")
```

#### Reference:

- [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)